# Wacom CTH-690 (Intuos 3d) cannot connect over wireless

Tags: macos

I have a brand new Intuos 3D tablet that I haven't used much, and recently I got a wireless kit and tried to make it work over wireless, with macOS High Sierra 10.13.4

- It worked for a few times, all keys and pen functioned properly.
- However, it stopped working early this week, I haven't been able to get it to connect since.
- The tablet search for usb receiver for 4 seconds as documented, then went back into sleep mode as none are found.
- I have went through all the usual troubleshooting, like recharging battery, clean install latest driver etc., but Wacom driver just refuse to recognize Intuos 3D, and vice versa.
- But, wired usb connection still works, so I know the tablet itself is fine.
- There are no more info other than the cold "No Tablets Were Found" / "No device connected" status.
- CTH-690 is supported by latest wacom driver, and I have tried clean install latest driver (6.3.30-2) and the previous stable (6.3.29-6), no luck at all.
- The wireless usb receiver/kit is *factory-paired*, so there is no pairing issue here.

**I desperately need some way to troubleshoot this, command line or otherwise, help much appreciated!**

reference:

- http://101.wacom.com/UserHelp/en/WirelessConnection.htm
- https://www.wacom.com/en/support/product-support/drivers
- https://www.wacom.com/en/products/pen-tablets/intuos-3d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have given Wacom Support a call and guess what, they DID know about this, and the solution is something I couldn't believe:

> **Just pull out the usb receiver from the Macbook's port slightly.**

This is the first solution the tech support offered and it worked.

Turns out the wireless kit is ever-so-slightly incompatible with the usb port Macbook Pro uses, pushing the receiver completely into the usb port caused this issue (where the usb receiver isn't detected by macOS).

So there, I learned something new today.